# Serial getty service stops during boot

Tags: systemd, yocto

I'm working on an embedded device running a Yocto based Linux distribution.

Others appear to have faced [this exact issue](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000EbO9A/systemd-didnt-generate-a-devttystm0device-unit-and-therefore-stopped-getty) under different conditions but don't seem to have found a solution.

I've taken the stock OpenSTLinux distribution and started remove layers one by one (e.g. X11) and in the process have broken something that takes away the serial login console.

The strange thing is, the login prompt is present when I boot the device the first time after writing the sdcard image. However, on subsequent boots, the login prompt is no longer there.

The boot messages (printed via) the serial port indicates that:

- The console parameter is passed to the kernel
- The serial port in question is properly initialised
- The serial Getty instance is started, but immediately stops

```
Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.61 (oe-user@oe-host) (arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.34.0.20200220) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 26 12:51:21 1
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: STMicroelectronics STM32MP157F-DK2 Discovery Board
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x10000000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node mcuram2@10000000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x10040000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node vdev0vring0@10040000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x10041000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node vdev0vring1@10041000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x10042000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node vdev0buffer@10042000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x10048000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node mcu_rsc_table@10048000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x30000000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node mcuram@30000000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x38000000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node retram@38000000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 128 MiB at 0xc7800000
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000dfffffff]
[    0.000000]   HighMem  empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000d3ffffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000d4000000-0x00000000d7ffffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000d8000000-0x00000000dfcfffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000dfd00000-0x00000000dffeffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000dfff0000-0x00000000dfffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x00000000c0000000-0x00000000dfffffff]
[    0.000000] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    0.000000] psci: PSCIv1.1 detected in firmware.
[    0.000000] psci: Using standard PSCI v0.2 function IDs
[    0.000000] psci: MIGRATE_INFO_TYPE not supported.
[    0.000000] psci: SMC Calling Convention v1.2
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 20 pages/cpu s51788 r8192 d21940 u81920
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 129920

[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=PARTUUID=e91c4e10-16e6-4c0e-bd0e-77becf4a3582 rootwait rw    console=ttySTM0,115200


[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 297404K/524288K available (11264K kernel code, 1207K rwdata, 3308K rodata, 1024K init, 239K bss, 95812K reserved, 131072K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU event tracing is enabled.
[    0.000000]  Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x388/0x560 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 24.00MHz (virt).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x588fe9dc0, max_idle_ns: 440795202592 ns
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 56 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 4398046511097ns
[    0.000024] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 41ns
[    0.001420] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001477] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 48.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=240000)
[    0.001503] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001721] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.001743] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.002888] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003300] /cpus/cpu@0 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.003342] /cpus/cpu@1 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.003359] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.004407] Setting up static identity map for 0xc0100000 - 0xc0100060
[    0.004588] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.005816] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.006874] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.007094] smp: Brought up 1 node, 2 CPUs
[    0.007120] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (96.00 BogoMIPS).
[    0.007132] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.007882] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.037995] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.038325] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.038358] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.044500] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.046193] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.049095] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.050729] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.051131] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.051484] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.051503] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.051847] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.095434] stm32-pm-domain pm_domain: domain core-ret-power-domain registered
[    0.095479] stm32-pm-domain pm_domain: subdomain core-power-domain registered
[    0.095494] stm32-pm-domain pm_domain: domains probed
[    0.118494] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.119253] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.119330] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.119409] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.119669] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.119684] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.119716] PTP clock support registered
[    0.120538] arm-scmi firmware:scmi0: SCMI Notifications - Core Enabled.
[    0.120621] arm-scmi firmware:scmi0: SCMI Protocol v2.0 'ST:' Firmware version 0x0
[    0.123567] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    1.235280] simple-framebuffer dfd00000.framebuffer: framebuffer at 0xdfd00000, 0xbb800 bytes, mapped to 0x(ptrval)
[    1.235313] simple-framebuffer dfd00000.framebuffer: format=r5g6b5, mode=480x800x16, linelength=960
[    1.235745] simple-framebuffer dfd00000.framebuffer: fb0: simplefb registered!
[    1.247748] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    1.248000] IP idents hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    1.249208] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
[    1.249362] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    1.249423] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    1.249502] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    1.249666] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    1.249714] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    1.250289] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    1.251232] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    1.251258] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    1.251269] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    1.251280] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    1.251624] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    1.547733] Freeing initrd memory: 3548K
[    1.548702] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    1.550424] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.550811] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    1.559823] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    1.561119] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.561177] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.561189] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.561340] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.561356] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.561538] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O].
[    1.561806] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) �© 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    1.562580] fuse: init (API version 7.32)
[    1.563491] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[    1.563518] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.563531] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.563687] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 246)
[    1.563705] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.563717] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.575020] STM32 USART driver initialized
[    1.594625] brd: module loaded
[    1.599100] random: fast init done
[    1.603858] random: crng init done
[    1.606905] loop: module loaded
[    1.611950] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.613824] CAN device driver interface
[    1.615651] pegasus: v0.9.3 (2013/04/25), Pegasus/Pegasus II USB Ethernet driver
[    1.615738] usbcore: registered new interface driver pegasus
[    1.615812] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
[    1.615866] usbcore: registered new interface driver ax88179_178a
[    1.615917] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[    1.615984] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc75xx
[    1.616061] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.616114] usbcore: registered new interface driver net1080
[    1.616166] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_subset
[    1.616216] usbcore: registered new interface driver zaurus
[    1.616292] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ncm
[    1.617608] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.617668] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.618061] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.618100] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    1.618735] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.622124] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.626527] stm32-cpufreq stm32-cpufreq: Failed to get chip info: -517
[    1.627688] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.627708] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.627718] Synopsys Designware Multimedia Card Interface Driver
[    1.628129] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.629272] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.629504] SMCCC: SOC_ID: ID = jep106:0020:0500 Revision = 0x00002001
[    1.629917] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.629933] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.631216] remoteproc remoteproc0: releasing m4
[    1.633687] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.633733] can: controller area network core
[    1.633848] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    1.633862] can: raw protocol
[    1.633877] can: broadcast manager protocol
[    1.633897] can: netlink gateway - max_hops=1
[    1.634634] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.634797] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    1.634826] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.635245] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.635271] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.671331] stm32-mdma 58000000.dma-controller: STM32 MDMA driver registered
[    1.674576] stm32-dma 48000000.dma-controller: STM32 DMA driver registered
[    1.676863] stm32-dma 48001000.dma-controller: STM32 DMA driver registered
[    1.685886] stm_thermal 50028000.thermal: stm_thermal_probe: Driver initialized successfully
[    1.692265] remoteproc remoteproc0: releasing m4
[    1.693045] /soc/interrupt-controller@5000d000: bank0
[    1.693069] /soc/interrupt-controller@5000d000: bank1
[    1.693085] /soc/interrupt-controller@5000d000: bank2
[    1.697079] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOA bank added
[    1.698997] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOB bank added
[    1.700879] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOC bank added
[    1.702782] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOD bank added
[    1.704755] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOE bank added
[    1.706924] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOF bank added
[    1.708740] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOG bank added
[    1.710511] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOH bank added
[    1.712226] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: GPIOI bank added
[    1.712535] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller@50002000: Pinctrl STM32 initialized
[    1.715425] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller-z@54004000: GPIOZ bank added
[    1.715464] stm32mp157-pinctrl soc:pin-controller-z@54004000: Pinctrl STM32 initialized
[    1.718602] 4000e000.serial: ttySTM3 at MMIO 0x4000e000 (irq = 61, base_baud = 4000000) is a stm32-usart
[    1.718929] serial serial0: tty port ttySTM3 registered
[    1.720797] stm32-usart 40010000.serial: interrupt mode for rx (no dma)
[    1.720823] stm32-usart 40010000.serial: interrupt mode for tx (no dma)


[    1.720858] 40010000.serial: ttySTM0 at MMIO 0x40010000 (irq = 62, base_baud = 4000000) is a stm32-usart
[    2.965639] printk: console [ttySTM0] enabled


...
Welcome to ST OpenSTLinux - Weston - (A Yocto Project Based Distro) 3.1.11-snapshot-20211216 (dunfell)!

[    5.867882] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <stm32mp1>.
[    5.882917] systemd[1]: Hardware watchdog 'STM32 Independent Watchdog', version 0
[    5.890326] systemd[1]: Set hardware watchdog to 32s.


[    6.505443] systemd[1]: Unnecessary job for /dev/ttySTM0 was removed.


[    6.517357] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    6.557278] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    6.597028] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    6.634855] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Dispatch Password �…ts to Console Directory Watch.
[    6.674597] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password R�…uests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    6.714486] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[    6.744085] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[    6.784102] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[  OK  ] Reached target Slices.
[    6.814158] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[    6.884002] systemd[1]: Listening on RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on RPCbind Server Activation Socket.
[    6.924179] systemd[1]: Reached target RPC Port Mapper.
[  OK  ] Reached target RPC Port Mapper.
[    6.965725] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    7.026252] systemd[1]: Listening on Process Core Dump Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Process Core Dump Socket.
[    7.064801] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[  OK  ] Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    7.113194] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Journal Audit Socket being skipped.
[    7.121650] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[  OK  ] Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    7.155508] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Journal Socket.
[    7.195987] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[    7.235479] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    7.274985] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    7.315694] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Huge Pages File System being skipped.
[    7.333008] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
         Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    7.384647] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
         Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    7.437495] systemd[1]: Mounting Temporary Directory (/tmp)...
         Mounting Temporary Directory (/tmp)...
[    7.485149] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
         Starting Create list of st�…odes for the current kernel...
[    7.545605] systemd[1]: Starting RPC Bind...
         Starting RPC Bind...
[    7.574602] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in File System Check on Root Device being skipped.
[    7.592953] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
         Starting Journal Service...
[    7.627247] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Load Kernel Modules being skipped.
[    7.640351] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
         Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    7.660372] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
         Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[    7.684598] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    7.732844] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    7.744149] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    7.775175] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    7.846450] systemd[1]: Started RPC Bind.
[  OK  ] Started RPC Bind.
[    7.884892] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[  OK  ] Started Journal Service.
[  OK  ] Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted Temporary Directory (/tmp).
[  OK  ] Started Create list of sta�… nodes for the current kernel.
[  OK  ] Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[  OK  ] Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[  OK  ] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
         Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
[    8.261556] systemd-journald[257]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
         Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[  OK  ] Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
[  OK  ] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
         Mounting /var/volatile...
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[  OK  ] Mounted /var/volatile.
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[  OK  ] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Set.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on dropbear.socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Started Kernel Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[    9.739841] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.742261] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    9.771239] st,stm32-i2s 4000b000.audio-controller: No cache defaults, reading back from HW
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[    9.808251] stm32-cryp 54001000.cryp: will run requests pump with realtime priority
[    9.816453] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.821463] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.834299] stm32-hash 54002000.hash: will run requests pump with realtime priority
[  OK  ] Started Gett[    9.899739] stm32-cryp 54001000.cryp: Initialized
y on tty1.
[    9.914298] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.918052] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
         Starting IPv6 Packet Filtering Framework...
         Starting IPv4 Packet Filtering Framework...


[  OK  ] Started Serial Getty on ttySTM0.
[   10.030315] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   10.043752] stm32-hash 54002000.hash: Init HASH done HW ver 23 DMA mode 1
[   10.051633] stm32-crc32 58009000.crc: Initialized
         Stopping Serial Getty on ttySTM0...


         Starting Login Service...
[   10.129884] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   10.144424] galcore: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  OK  ] Started TEE Supplicant.
[   10.171541] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[  OK  ] Started IPv6 Packet Filtering Framework.
[  OK  ] Started IPv4 Packet Filtering Framework.
[   10.351280] Galcore version 6.4.3.279124
[   10.363263] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database


[  OK  ] Stopped Serial Getty on ttySTM0.


[   10.480989] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[   10.551612] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[   10.564325] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[   10.567851] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 94
[   10.572661] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2e
[   10.579068] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1
[   10.581554] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1 (001.002.009) build 0000
[   10.593980] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1 'brcm/BCM43430A1.hcd' Patch
[   10.719466] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   10.944323] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
[   11.034191] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Feb 16 2020 22:39:24 version 7.45.98.97 (r724416 CY) FWID 01-bf41ed64
[   11.246819] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM4343WA1 37.4MHz Murata Type-1DX BT4.2-0093
[   11.252320] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1 (001.002.009) build 0395
[   11.337201] cs42l51 0-004a: Cirrus Logic CS42L51, Revision: 01
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
[  OK  ] Reached target Bluetooth.
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network (Pre).
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Reached target Hardware activated USB gadget.
         Starting Load/Save Screen �…of backlight:5a000000.dsi.0...
         Starting Network Service...
[FAILED] Failed to start Load/Save �…s of backlight:5a000000.dsi.0.
See 'systemctl status systemd-backlight�…ht:5a000000.dsi.0.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started Network Service.
         Starting Network Name Resolutio[   12.423795] stm32-dwmac 5800a000.ethernet eth0: PHY [stmmac-0:00] driver [RTL8211F Gigabit Ethernet] (irq=POLL)
n...
[   12.438978] dwmac4: Master AXI performs any burst length
[   12.442981] stm32-dwmac 5800a000.ethernet eth0: No Safety Features support found
[   12.451037] stm32-dwmac 5800a000.ethernet eth0: IEEE 1588-2008 Advanced Timestamp supported
[   12.460125] stm32-dwmac 5800a000.ethernet eth0: registered PTP clock
[   12.468558] stm32-dwmac 5800a000.ethernet eth0: configuring for phy/rgmii-id link mode
[  OK  ] Started Network Name Resolution.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
[  OK  ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Reached target Multi-User System.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[   16.716957] stm32-dwmac 5800a000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   16.724237] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   33.753839] usb33: supplied by vdd_usb
[   33.756433] vref: supplied by vdd
[   33.759707] vref: disabling
[   33.762296] vdda: disabling
```

The status of the Getty service indicates that it has stopped due to the serial device being inactive:

```
$ systemctl status serial-getty@ttySTM0.service

● serial-getty@ttySTM0.service - Serial Getty on ttySTM0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-12-22 20:15:56 UTC; 3min 35s ago
       Docs: man:agetty(8)
             man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
             http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
    Process: 321 ExecStart=/sbin/agetty -8 --autologin root -L ttySTM0 115200 $TERM (code=killed, signal=HUP)
   Main PID: 321 (code=killed, signal=HUP)

Dec 22 20:15:56 stm32mp1 systemd[1]: Started Serial Getty on ttySTM0.
Dec 22 20:15:56 stm32mp1 systemd[1]: serial-getty@ttySTM0.service: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-ttySTM0.device. Stopping, too.
Dec 22 20:15:56 stm32mp1 systemd[1]: Stopping Serial Getty on ttySTM0...
Dec 22 20:15:56 stm32mp1 systemd[1]: serial-getty@ttySTM0.service: Succeeded.
Dec 22 20:15:56 stm32mp1 systemd[1]: Stopped Serial Getty on ttySTM0.
```

However, the device listing indicates that it is available and active:

```
$ systemctl --all --full -t device

UNIT                                                                                           LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION                                     
...
dev-ttySTM0.device                                                                             loaded active plugged /dev/ttySTM0                                          
...
```

Could anyone suggest what the issue might be?

Or could you suggest what else I can do to find the source of the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Fine analysis, but maybe it's easier to identify the very layer you did remove to cause the problem and find the change in configuration or recipe.

Comment: @Philippos, I did spend a few hours sifting through the layers that I removed, but as the answer shows, the problem was something entirely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually, worked out what the issue was.

The vendor has provided a recipe to override the contents of the `/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service` file.

So while the upstream sources contained the following line:

```
After=dev-%i.device systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service getty-pre.target
```

The service file that ended up on the rootfs modified the line to:

```
After=systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service getty-pre.target
```

The end result is a race condition that sometimes caused the serial getty service to fail due to the device not yet being available.

I had to hack into the systemd sources to add some debug messages to see the exact sequence of events.